# OpenCV with Java - UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.dicomJpgMatRead_0

Tags: java, opencv, dcm4che

I am using dcm4che3 to decompress a compressed dicom image in Ubuntu 18.04.

while I could get the native library loaded for OpenCV, but still I am getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError while calling Transcoder.transcode(...)

I wonder what I am missing here.

> 23:03:56.694 [main] DEBUG org.dcm4che3.imageio.codec.Transcoder -
> Decompressor: org.dcm4che3.opencv.NativeImageReader
> Mar 06, 2021 11:03:56 PM org.opencv.osgi.OpenCVNativeLoader init
> INFO: Successfully loaded OpenCV native library.
> 23:03:56.769 [main] DEBUG ****************: thrown java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError(org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.dicomJpgMatRead_0(JII)J)
> out of org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs#dicomJpgMatRead_0[-2] in 219ms

Stacktrace:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.dicomJpgMatRead_0(JII)J
> at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.dicomJpgMatRead_0(Native Method) ~[weasis-opencv-core-3.6.0-rc1.jar:na]
> at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.dicomJpgMatRead(Imgcodecs.java:219)
> ~[weasis-opencv-core-3.6.0-rc1.jar:na]
> at org.dcm4che3.opencv.NativeImageReader.getNativeImage(NativeImageReader.java:287)
> ~[dcm4che-imageio-opencv-5.22.1.jar:na]
> at org.dcm4che3.opencv.NativeImageReader.read(NativeImageReader.java:251)
> ~[dcm4che-imageio-opencv-5.22.1.jar:na]
> at org.dcm4che3.imageio.codec.Transcoder.decompressFrame(Transcoder.java:620)
> ~[dcm4che-imageio-5.22.1.jar:5.22.1]
> at org.dcm4che3.imageio.codec.Transcoder.decompressPixelData(Transcoder.java:453)
> ~[dcm4che-imageio-5.22.1.jar:5.22.1]
> at org.dcm4che3.imageio.codec.Transcoder.processPixelData(Transcoder.java:434)
> ~[dcm4che-imageio-5.22.1.jar:5.22.1]
> at org.dcm4che3.imageio.codec.Transcoder.access$300(Transcoder.java:70)
> ~[dcm4che-imageio-5.22.1.jar:5.22.1]
> at org.dcm4che3.imageio.codec.Transcoder$1.readValue(Transcoder.java:389)
> ~[dcm4che-imageio-5.22.1.jar:5.22.1]
> at org.dcm4che3.io.DicomInputStream.readAttributes(DicomInputStream.java:534)
> ~[dcm4che-core-5.22.1.jar:5.22.1]
> at org.dcm4che3.imageio.codec.Transcoder.transcode(Transcoder.java:368)
> ~[dcm4che-imageio-5.22.1.jar:5.22.1]

Answer (score 0):

I turned to be the case of having the right path set for the envrionment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH; in my case, /app/open/java/bin had the required .so files.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/opencv/java/bin
```

To load the open cv library for junits, I had to provide the path in java.library.path:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Djava.library.path=/app/opencv/java/bin</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```